# Maximize sum of edge weights on spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, computer-science, combinatorial-optimization

> *Problem:* Given a complete graph with n vertices, the edge weight between vertex $i$ and vertex $j$ is $b[i]\times b[j]$.
>
> Under the condition that the degree of point $i$ on spanning tree is DEG $[i]$, let the sum of all edge weights on spanning tree is maximized.

I wonder if there is a polynomial time algorithm for this problem.

If so, what should the algorithm do? Why is it right? Has there been any discussion in the academic circle?

Answer (score 2):

This is the *degree-constrained spanning tree problem*, and it is NP-hard:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree-constrained_spanning_tree

Comment: How do I code degree constrained spanning tree as in instance of this problem?

Comment: Hmm, I guess the linked problem is only a relaxation (degree at most $k$ rather than a specified degree sequence).

Comment: I'm glad I asked for clarification as I hadn't realised that DEG was degree _in the spanning tree_, although I'm not sure what else would have made sense.

Comment: But,I am not sure DCST can reduce to this problem